# Issue with the doctrine-cli

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, mamp

I am having issues getting my database to build from my YAML file.

Here is the error:

```
./scripts/doctrine-cli build-all-load
build-all-load - Generated models successfully from YAML schema
build-all-load - Couldn't locate driver named mysql
build-all-load - Created tables successfully
build-all-load - Data was successfully loaded
```

It builds my models, but nothing in the database. I am using MAMP and I have checked and pdo_mysql is running. I am not completely sure why this would happen. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quite looks like `pdo_mysql` is not enabled ; you said you checked `php.ini`, but did you check the one that's used when PHP is run from the command line ?

*(That's often not the same as the one used when PHP is run as an Apache module)*

You can use `php -m` to get the list of loaded extensions :

```
$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
...
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
...
```

And `php -i`  should indicate which .ini file is used, when running PHP from the CLI :

```
$ php -i | grep 'ini'
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/apc.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
...
```

Comment: PHP from the command line was using the Mac default, I changed it over to the MAMP version. But still no tables created...

Now I get this message when it creates them, "Successfully created database for connection named '0'"

Comment: OK for the php.ini problem : that's good news ;;; for the problem you are now experiencing : are you sure the doctrine task you are using is actually supposed to create the tables ? (just a question ) seems odd it said "created tables successfully" earlier, and doesn't anymore

Comment: Oh it still says that too. I just copied the new line, sorry.

Comment: Corrected it, I had a model in there from my prototype version and Doctrine didn't like it. Now it all works great, thank you!